# Efficient way to change the particular text in particular color in strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, fonts

I designing a `Dictionary App` for Android tech words..it almost done..Now i need to style the views..So i am Desided to give Colors for keywords Code..In my String.xml,i have **`99+ string classes`**..

I used to change the font colour as like below mentioned Code..this code works

```
  <string name="xml_code">
    <![CDATA[<b><font color=#000080>&lt;LinearLayout</b><br><br>
            \t\t <b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_width=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"match_parent\"</b><br><br>
            \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_height=</b>><b><font color=#008000>\"match_parent\"</b><br><br>
            \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:orientation=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"vertical\"</b>&gt;<br><br>
    <b><font color=#000080>&lt;TextView</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_width=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"match_parent\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_height=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"wrap_content\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:text=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"Hello\"</b>/&gt;<br><br>
    <b><font color=#000080>&lt;ImageView</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_width=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"match_parent\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_height=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"wrap_content\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:src=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"@drawable/mountain\"</b>/&gt;<br><br>
    <b><font color=#000080>&lt;Button</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_width=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"match_parent\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:layout_height=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"wrap_content\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:text=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"Press me\"</b><br><br>
        \t\t<b><font color=#660E7A>android</b><b><font color=#0000FF>:onClick=</b><b><font color=#008000>\"doSomething\"</b>/&gt;<br><br>
    <b><font color=#000080>&lt;/LinearLayout&gt;</b>]]>
    </string>
```

In a Entire String,

```
if word is android,it should be violet
if word is layout:width/etc.. ,it should blue
if word is values,it should be green..
```

for my Above mentioned code,the output is
[image]

I need my output like the Screenshot..It works from above code..Can anyone say how to **`minimize the code to change the font Color`**..Because i need to change the font color for 99+ string classes..please give an Easiest way to change my font color..If you can't understand my Question,please ask me..

Comment: use `ForegroundColorSpan` and some `Spannable` class

Comment: did you ask uncle google for: `ForegroundColorSpan Spannable`? note `ForegroundColorSpan`, not `ForegroundSpan`

Comment: I search about ForegroundSpan and Spannable..but i am asking like this..Consider the  Single String "Android Application Development" ..In this String Android should be in Red Color,then Application Should be in blue Color,then Development should be in Green Color..Now do you Understand

Comment: not `ForegroundSpan`! search for `ForegroundColorSpan`

Comment: ok I am not sking that..please look up my screenshot..In my Screenshot the whole String is under single class..within the class i have to change the Diffrent font color to Diffrent words

Comment: so use `Spannable#setSpan` method, like it was done [here](http://www.android--tutorials.com/2016/07/android-how-to-create-textview.html)

Comment: thank you @pskink ..I understand..

Answer (score 0):

Hope it Works..

```
SpannableString styledString = "Ajay";
styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, 1, 0);
  // Give the styled string to a TextView
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  textView.setText(styledString);
```